# I need Regex and to find the occurrence of "Processing" keyword and print the following text if the first word is Processing

Tags: c#, regex, string

```
string s = textBox1.Text;
string[] lines = s.Split(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray());

foreach (string l in lines)
{
    if (Regex.IsMatch(lines.(Here when i select .ToString() i get no o/p), pattern))
    {
        textBox3.Text = textBox3.Text + l + Environment.NewLine+;
    }
}
```

for example if input is:

```
Processing \\Users\\bhargava\\Desktop\New.txt
Processing \\Users\\bhargava\\Desktop\\New2.txt
<get process by id>
Processing \\Users\\bhargava\\Desktop\New3.txt
<get element by id>
Processing \\Users\\bhargava\\Desktop\\New4.txt
```

output is:

```
Processing \\Users\\bhargava\\Desktop\New.txt
Processing \\Users\\bhargava\\Desktop\\New2.txt

Processing \\Users\\bhargava\\Desktop\New3.txt

Processing \\Users\\bhargava\\Desktop\\New4.txt
```

Comment: Um, you didn't ask a question.

Comment: There was a question, it was just hidden behind horrible formatting

Comment: @Chris, no there was definitely no question.  It was a problem statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a regex for this.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s.aspx

String.IndexOf(String) Reports the zero-based index of the first occurrence of the specified string in this instance. Returns -1 if the string does not occur in this instance.

e.g.

```
if (l.IndexOf("Processing") == 0)
{
    //do stuff
}
```

(For reference though, the regex would just be `Processing`)

Comment: @Bhargava Ram Whenever you need to do something and it sounds really simple, there's usually an implementation of it in one of the standard libraries/classes :) You are welcome